# Multiplying two arrays but it only contains the diagonal and the sub-diagonal of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication, diagonal

i have two `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;`

The two matrixes only stores the diagonal and the sub-diagonal numbers.
The two matrix have the same size
For example

2 0 6  
0 9 0
7 0 3

matrix[0] only has two elements, matrix[0][0] = 2 and matrix[0][1] = 6 ,matrix[1][0] = 9 etc...
I can't use arrays.

i tried this

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < x_matrix.size(); x++)
    {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < x_matrix[x].size(); y++)
        {
            for (unsigned int z = 0; z < x_matrix.size(); z++)
            {
                if (x_matrix[x].size() == y_matrix[z].size())
                {
                    solution_matrix[x][y] += x_matrix[x][z] * y_matrix[z][y];
                }





            }




        }

    }
```

and a lot more, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: do you know how to multiply matrices with pen and paper? `solution_matrix[x][y] = ...` in the inner-most loop cannot be correct. The `z` loop iterations overwrite the same value again and again

Comment: Please include a [mcve]